# Permanecer en la ruta al hacer F5 en Vuex, Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, router, laravel-sanctum

Estoy utilizando Laravel sanctum para el sistema de login entre Laravel y Vue, el sistema funciona perfecto al realizar el login, pero tengo un problema al hacer un F5 una vez ingrese a la aplicación.

tengo mi archivo store.js de esta forma

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/"

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: null,
    auth: false
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state, user) {
      state.user = user,
      state.auth = Boolean(user)
    }
  },
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    async logout( {dispatch} ) {
      await axios.post("/logout")
      localStorage.removeItem('email')
      return dispatch('getUser')
      
    },
    async login( {dispatch}, credentials) {
      await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
        await axios.post("/login", credentials)
          return dispatch('getUser')
    },
    getUser({commit} ) {
      axios.get("/api/user").then(res =>{
        commit ('SET_USER', res.data)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        commit ('SET_USER', null)
        
      })
    }
  }
})
```

y tengo mi router.js de esta forma:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import store from "../store/store";


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: { 
      requireAuth: true 
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/users/userlist',
    name: 'UserList',
    component: () => import('../views/users/UserList.vue'),
    meta: { 
      requireAuth: true 
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/Login.vue')
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    redirect: "/login",
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let loginRequired = to.matched.some((ruta) => ruta.meta.requireAuth);
  
    if (loginRequired && !store.state.user) {
      
      next('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
})



export default router
```

Acá he aplicado un middleware meta requireAuth y el router.beforeEach, con ello permito el acceso a las url solo cuando el usuario esta logeado, la sesión permanece sin ningun problema, y al cerrar cerrar sesión se bloquea el acceso, **el problema que tengo es que una vez logeado y navego a cualquier menu y dar f5, me redirecciona a la pestaña de login, sin cerrar la sesión en el sistema**

En imagen es lo siguiente:

1. Login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. ingrese al sistema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. realizo actualización de la pagina (F5) y me redirecciona a la url login, permaneciendo con la sesión de login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Entiendo que mi problema puede estar únicamente en el router.beforeEach**

main.js lo tengo asi:

```
store.dispatch('getUser').then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

Comment: Creería que al recargar la página se recrea la instancia de Vue. Estás teniendo en cuenta si `user` no está vacío antes de hacer `new Vue`?

Comment: he agregado a la consulta donde tengo esa parte... en el main.js

Comment: No te estará faltando un return en `getUser({commit} ) {
      return axios.get("/api/user")...`?

Comment: si revisas el archivo store.js lo encontraras... es el primer archivo del post, a ese haces referencia?

Comment: Sí, en ese archivo en el action `getUser`, decía agregar un return de axios para que devualva la promise.